# File within the folder does not work in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am creating an application and each screen of the application is in a different folder.
The problem is that when the files are in the folder and not in the www root, the resources of Phonegap not work.

This does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
```

How to use the resources of phonegap normally even with the files in a folder?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide code and screenshot of file directory to understand better what you are doing

Comment: I'm sorry I did not realize that the code was not showing up. I edited the code to appear.

Comment: I see, I don't know why you want to do that, typically all the files are stored inside the root dir www. I haven't try that but I suggest using the standards to avoid problems.

Comment: You can always use as many folders inside www to organize your stuff and it will work, I always do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that is setup like yours - here's how I *used* to handle it:

```
var rootURL = "";
if(inSubFolderMode()) rootURL = "../../";
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + rootURL + "phonegap.js"'></script>");
function inSubFolderMode(){
    return ((document.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf('WWW/SUBFOLER_PARENT/',0) > -1));
}
```

However after PhoneGap (Cordova) 2.9 this stopped working so now I just do this in each of my html pages - modifying the relative path accordingly.

```
<!-- root index page --> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- sub folder page -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../cordova.js"></script>
```

I preferred my old way because it's cleaner/more dry but something with how the function findCordovaPath() works had changed I think. If you want more detail on this see this issue for when I was struggling/researching this myself: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4708

Helpful?